# Drunkard wolverine

Tags: combinatorics, induction, puzzle

I'd like to ask for some hint for the following math exercise below. I've been working on it for days now and it drives me crazy.

> There is a drunkard wolverine who drinks at least $1$ mug of beer every day. (The number of mugs per day is an integer. The wolverine lives forever, so there are infinitely many days.) Every week the wolverine drinks $12$ mugs of beer in total. Prove that one can choose some consecutive days where the number of consumed mugs of beer is $20$.
>
> (A "week" means $7$ days from Monday to Sunday.)

This can be translated into algebraic language; then it says that if $\left(\ldots, m_{-1}, m_0, m_1, m_2, \ldots\right)$ is a sequence of positive integers (infinite in both directions) such that $m_{7i+1} + m_{7i+2} + \cdots + m_{7i+7} = 12$ for each integer $i$, then there exist $u \leq v$ such that $m_u + m_{u+1} + \cdots + m_v = 20$.

The problem is similar to Example 6 of http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/jing/222pigeonhole.pdf .

Comment: pigeonhole principle.

Comment: There is some missing information... How many days does the wolverine drink? (e.g., if you only have one week of data, this is impossible)

Comment: Key word is every @angryavian

Comment: In particular, two weeks of data is not enough: a counterexample is $1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6$.

Comment: @angryavian You have a seven day period where the wolverine only drinks seven beers. Does every week mean starting and ending on a fixed day or does it mean every seven day period?

Comment: @JohnDouma - it's best to wait for OP to clarify, but the question becomes kinda weird if "a week" = "any consecutive $7$ days period", because in this interpretation, the drinking pattern would have to be periodic with period $7$ - as one day moves out of the moving window, another day moves into the window, and the number of beers in both days must be equal s.t. each window contains exactly $12$ beers.

Comment: @angryavian - your deleted answer (which I can see for some reason) almost works.  you just need another week: $a_{[1:21]} + 20$ has range $[21,56]$ and $a_{[15:35]}$ has range $[25,60]$ so the union has range $[21,60]$ of size only $40$.  pls revive your answer, fix it, and get the credit due.  :)

Comment: @antkam Thanks so much for the fix!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: For a period of three consecutive weeks, keep track of the total number of beers the wolverine has consumed, mod $20$. This number will start at $1$ on the Monday of the first week and end at $16$ on the final Sunday, at which point the Wolverine has consumed a total of $36$ beers.

Rest of solution below:

> Since there are $21$ days altogether and only $20$ residues mod $20$, the pigeonhole principle says some residue must repeat within the three-week period, which means the wolverine has consumed some multiple of $20$ beers from the first of those two days to the second. But the only (positive) multiple of $20$ less than $36$ is $20$ itself.

Comment: I'm ashamed of not being able to solve this myself... :( Anyway thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_i$ be the total number of mugs drunk on days $1$ through $i$.

$a_1,a_2,\ldots$ is a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers, such that $a_{7k} = 12k$ for positive integers $k$.

It turns out that it suffices to look at the first $35$ days.

Consider $a_{15}, a_{16}, \ldots,a_{35}, a_1+20, a_2+20,\ldots, a_{21}+20$. This is a list of $42$ numbers ranging from $21$ to $60$, so some number must appear [at least] twice in that list. Because $(a_i)$ is strictly increasing, $a_{15},\ldots, a_{35}$ must be distinct, and $a_1+20, \ldots, a_{21} +20$ must be distinct. Can you conclude from here?

---

Note that this answer is inferior to Barry Cipra's since this answer requires 35 days while his requires only 21.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer by @BarryCipra is tight, in the sense that we cannot prove it using $20$ (or fewer) days.

Here is a drinking schedule, listing the cumulative consumption after the first $20$ days.

- week $1: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12$
- week $2: 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 24$
- week $3$ (minus last day)$: 26, 28, 30, 33, 34, 35$

It is clear that no pair of numbers differ by $20$ (or in Barry's context, we have used every residue of mod $20$ exactly once).

Answer (score 0):

Every week the wolverine drinks 12 mugs with one guaranteed per day, so using the sticks and stones method, there are $\dbinom{12-7+6}{6}=462$ ways the wolverine can drink beer in one week. Hopefully this helps in some way.

Comment: aka stars and bars.