# Given $A = \{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{m - 1}, a_m\}$ and $B = \{b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{n - 1}, b_n\}$. Prove that $\exists a \in A, b \in B, a + b = p$.

Tags: combinatorics

> Given sets $A = \{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{m - 1}, a_m\}$ and $B = \{b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{n - 1}, b_n\}$ such that
>
> - $A \cup B \subseteq \mathbb N \cap [1, p), p \in \mathbb N, p > 2$
> - $m + n > p$
>
> Prove that $\exists a \in A \wedge b \in B, a + b = p$.

We have that $\max m = \max n = |\mathbb N \cap [1, p)| = p - 1$.

Assuming that $\forall a \in A$ and $b \in B, a + b \ne p$, we need to prove that $m + n \le p$.

For the case of $m + n = p$, we have that $$\forall a \in A \wedge b \in B, \exists a' \in A \wedge a' \not\in B, b' \in B \wedge b' \not\in A, a + a' = b + b' = p$$

But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: What does $i,j=\overline{1,n}$ mean? -- Can we simplify the conditions to: $A,B$ are finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ and $|A|+|B|>\max\{A\cup B\}$?

Comment: I am a bit puzzled ... Take $p=3$ and sets $A=B=\{2,3\}$ ($m=n=2$ so $m+n=4>p$). Still you cannot get the sum $p$ from any two elements $a\in A, B\in B$. I suspect that there is some sort of "off-by-one" mistake in the problem statement.

Comment: When you say $i,j=\overline{1,m}$, do you mean $1\leq i,j\leq m$?

Comment: It means that $\forall i, j \in \{1, 2, \cdots, m - 1, m\}$.

Comment: Stinking Bishop, I have fixed the problem accordingly, it is now $A \cup B \subseteq \mathbb N \cap [1, p - 1]$.

Comment: Isn't the second bullet implied by the fact that they are *sets*, not *multisets*?

Comment: Right, it's just there for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

If I understand you correctly, the second bullet simply means all the $a_i$'s are distinct (i.e. $A$ has $m$ distinct elements) and all the $b_j$'s are distinct (i.e. $B$ has $n$ distinct elements).

If so, this seems to be a basic application of pigeonhole principle.

Suppose you are asked to prove $\exists a \in A \land b \in B, a = b$, that would be trivial because $m+n > p$, right?  But the original question is just as trivial if you consider arithmetic modulo $p$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: I must touch on the pigeonhole principle from now on, I have seen it being used in many solutions to combinatorics problems and yet, I do not know what its purpose is.

Comment: @LêThànhĐạt - there are obviously lots of pigeonhole problems on MSE.  here's a [recent one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3489600/drunkard-wolverine) which i enjoyed.  hope you like it too!